# PHP Registry Pattern

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I've found the piece of code below in several places around the web and even here on Stack Overflow, but I just can't wrap my head around it. I know what it does, but I don't know how it does it even with the examples. Basically it's storing values, but I don't know how I add values to the registry. Can someone please try to explain how this code works, both how I set and retrieve values from it?

```
class Registry {

    private $vars = array();

    public function __set($key, $val) {
        $this->vars[$key] = $val;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->vars[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should prevent the set function from overwriting with something like the following (also uses array_key_exists, should use for both set and get in this case) which is probably just as important as not using non-existent keys because the whole purpose of the registry is to store information, which is kind of defeated by the possibility of overwriting: `public function set($key, $val) { if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->_nfo)) { $this->_nfo[$key] = $val; } }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's using PHP's hacked on [property overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) to add entries to and retrieve entries from the private `$vars` array.

To add a property, you would use...

```
$registry = new Registry;
$registry->foo = "foo";
```

Internally, this would add a `foo` key to the `$vars` array with string value "foo" via the magic `__set` method.

To retrieve a value...

```
$foo = $registry->foo;
```

Internally, this would retrieve the `foo` entry from the `$vars` array via the magic `__get` method.

The `__get` method should really be checking for non-existent entries and handle such things. The code as-is will trigger an `E_NOTICE` error for an undefined index.

A better version might be

```
public function __get($key)
{
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->vars)) {
        return $this->vars[$key];
    }

    // key does not exist, either return a default
    return null;

    // or throw an exception
    throw new OutOfBoundsException($key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going crazy. This helped me go back and check what was going on. I was trying to set a form action, but it was always coming up blank. Turns out I was on the index page, so there was no value. DOH!. I tried the form on another page and it worked fine. Thanks for your help. When you say hacked on, does that mean it shouldn't be used this way?

Comment: @IanHoar Well, it definitely shouldn't be called *overloading*

Comment: @Phil I can see how you add the key, but how do you add a key-value pair?

Comment: @Wolfpack Not sure what you mean. When you set `$registry->key = 'value'`, internally it stores a key / value pair of `key` and `value` respectively but to the outside world, they appear as class properties

Comment: `$foo = $registry->foo;` ; `$foo = $registry->foo = 'bar';`?  I don't full understand the purpose of this code, honestly.  I'm just reading articles.

Comment: @Wolfpack still not sure what your question is. Your first snippet uses the `__get()` method to retrieve property `foo` and assign the value to local var `$foo`. Your second assigns `'bar'` to both the property `foo` and local variable `$foo`. It's no different to `$a = $b = 'some value'`

Comment: @Phil I was just following the template: `$registry->key = 'value'`

Answer (score 9):

You might want to check out [PHP.NET - Overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

Basically, you would do...

```
$Registry = new Registry();

$Registry->a = 'a'; //Woo I'm using __set
echo $Registry->a; //Wooo! I'm using __get
```

So here, I'm using `__set($a, 'This value is not visible to the scope or nonexistent')`
Also, I'm using `__get($a);`

Hope this helped!