# Confused about __get and __set in MVC framework design

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, overloading

I've been reading up on how exactly MVC frameworks work and the design pattern itself. I can understand most parts and see how it all fits together, but on a lot of examples I've seen something like this:

```
class Registry
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function __set($index, $value)
    {
      $this->vars[$index] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($index)
    {
      return $this->vars[$index];
    }
}
```

In a lot of tutorials it's called the "registry". It is usually instantiated in the `init` file and is part of calling a core class(route handler, templating etc.), for example rendering a view in your controller like this `$this->registry->template->render('view');`.

Reading the code 'word' for word I can see what it does, `$this->vars[$index] = $value`, takes the index from the `vars[]` array and makes it equal to `$value`. So, if we did:

```
__set(1, 'firstname');

// So now
$vars[1] = 'firstname';

__get(1); // Returns 'firstname'
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Faintly I can see the benefits and how useful this is, but I can't yet grasp the bigger picture. I can't tie it to the rest of the components and it seems to be a large part.

I can't wrap my head around as to what its purpose is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a design discussion than something more concise like a code debug. So..

[This tells you why its a good idea](http://www.brandonsavage.net/use-registry-to-remember-objects-so-you-dont-have-to/)

[This tells you why it is not](http://www.brandonsavage.net/the-registry-pattern-reexamined/)

[And this tells you about the registry getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147207/php-registry-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

`__get()` and `__set()` are so called [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). The benefit of them is, that you don't have to call them, they will be called by the PHP interpreter itself. This happens if you try to access non accessible properties of an object. This is called [property overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

Try this:

```
class Test {

    private $foo;

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        echo "assgning $name => $value";
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->foo = 'bar';
```