# PHP: Globals, SuperGlobals - How to make a variable's value accessible to all functions?

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a PHP program I'm writing which is about 200 lines of code. It has many functions I wrote, perhaps a dozen. I want to have a debug option in the program, but want that value to be accessible within all the functions as well. How and where should this be defined?

```
Global $debug_status;

function blah ($message) {
if ($debug_status == "1" ) {
  do something...}
...
}
```

Is this the right approach? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use **Globlas** you can use Registry Pattern to achieve it. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147207/php-registry-pattern

Comment: I should mention, this program isn't OO. Does that matter?

Comment: You could uses constants, since they are not bound to scopes.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: `define('DEBUG_STATUS', 1);` and `DEBUG_STATUS` will be accessible from everywhere for all bottom code lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a constant.

```
define('DEBUG', true);
```

...

```
if (DEBUG) ...
```

There are of course better ways to debug. For example, use OOP, inject a logger instance into each of your objects, call

```
$this->logger->debug(...);
```

to log messages, switch the output filter of the logger to show or hide debug messages.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there .... the global keyword imports a reference to a global into the current scope.

```
$debug_status = "ERROR";

function blah ($message) {
    global $debug_status;
    if ($debug_status == "1" ) {
      do something...}
      ...
    }
```

Comment: So you must define the variable global inside each function?

Comment: correct... another option is you can access it from the globals super global via `$GLOBALS["debug_status"]` but both of these techniques completely ignore scope and the benifits that it provides.

Answer (score 1):

The variable should be defined in Registry class which is sort of pattern.

[Working demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xJ1rn5)

**Example of Registry**

```
class Registry {
   private static $registry = array();

   private function __construct() {} //the object can be created only within a class.
   public static function set($key, $value) { // method to set variables/objects to registry
      self::$registry[$key] = $value;
   }

   public static function get($key) { //method to get variable if it exists from registry
      return isset(self::$registry[$key]) ? self::$registry[$key] : null;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

To register object you need include this classn

```
$registry::set('debug_status', $debug_status); //this line sets object in **registry**
```

To get the object you can use **get** method

```
$debug_status = $registry::get('debug_status'); //this line gets the object from **registry**
```

This is solution that every object/variable can be stored in. For such purpose as you wrote it's good to use simple constant and `define()`.

My solution is good for every kind of object that should be accessed from anywhere in application.

**Edit**

Removed singleton and make get, set methods as static as @deceze suggested.

Comment: Why not make the whole `Registry` and all its methods `static`? Why go through the trouble of statically getting an instance to get keys, why not `Registry::get('debug_status')` directly? Seems like the worst of both worlds. → [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Comment: Obviosly it can be done using static methods but there is no difference in working both solutions will work. What you suggest is shorter which maybe be better :)

Comment: I've changed the solution using static methods as @deceze suggested.